# Add column with counts of another, depending on another column

Tags: r

My question is an extension of this one : [Create a column with a count of occurrences in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592041/create-a-column-with-a-count-of-occurrences-in-r)

Given their example, I would like to see a count of how many of each products each person has.

I have a very large dataset which has this structure:

```
df <- c(Contact.ID, Date.Time, Week, Attendance, WeeklyAT)

 Contact.ID       Date    Time    Week   Attendance  *WeeklyAT 
1   A       2012-10-06 18:54:48   44         30          *2
2   A       2012-10-08 20:50:18   44         30          *2
3   A       2013-05-24 20:18:44   21         30          *1
4   B       2012-11-15 16:58:15   46         40          *1 
5   B       2013-01-09 10:57:02    2         40          *3
6   B       2013-01-11 17:31:22    2         40          *3
7   B       2013-01-14 18:37:00    2         40          *3
8   C       2013-02-22 17:46:07    8         5           *1
9   C       2013-02-27 11:21:00    9         5           *1
10  D       2012-10-28 14:48:33   43         12          *1
```

I am trying to find the `WeeklyAT` column, counting how often a week number occurs PER ID (which is the difference to the other question as I am not looking at general occurrence or count of weeks per ID)

I have tried these two approaches and mixtures of them but can't seem to find the right one:

`df <- transform(df, WeeklyAT = ave(seq(nrow(df)), Gym$Week, FUN=length))`

`df <- within(df, {
  WeeklyAT = ave(df$Week, df$Contact.ID, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))
})`

I greatly appreciate any help or tip :) Many Thanks.

Comment: `ave(df$Week, df$Week, df$Contact.ID, FUN = length)`

Comment: See `group_by` and `tally` or just `n` in `dplyr`.

Comment: @d.b works perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table` you could do something like the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
merge(df, df[, WeeklyAT := .N, by = .(Contact.ID, Week)])

       Contact.ID       Date     Time Week Attendance X.WeeklyAT WeeklyAT
 1:          A 2012-10-06 18:54:48   44         30         *2        2
 2:          A 2012-10-08 20:50:18   44         30         *2        2
 3:          A 2013-05-24 20:18:44   21         30         *1        1
 4:          B 2012-11-15 16:58:15   46         40         *1        1
 5:          B 2013-01-09 10:57:02    2         40         *3        3
 6:          B 2013-01-11 17:31:22    2         40         *3        3
 7:          B 2013-01-14 18:37:00    2         40         *3        3
 8:          C 2013-02-22 17:46:07    8          5         *1        1
 9:          C 2013-02-27 11:21:00    9          5         *1        1
10:          D 2012-10-28 14:48:33   43         12         *1        1
```

**EDIT:**

Apparently `dplyr`can do something very similar:

```
library(dplyr)
merge(df, 
      df %>% group_by(Contact.ID, Week) %>% summarise(WeeklyAT = n()))
```